# Activerecord query where current employer is X and previous employer is Y

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Basically I'd like to return all people whose current job title is X and whose previous job title is Y. As an example, I have a talent whose current emnployment is "Airbnb (company_id = 1)" and whose previous employment is at "Youtube (company_id = 2)".

If I run a query to find talent where current employment is Airbnb:

```
 Talent.joins(:job_histories).where(["job_histories.company_id = ? and job_histories.end_year = ?", 1, "Present"])
```

I get the person.

If I run a query where previous employment is Youtube (hence the end_year != "Present" below)

```
Talent.joins(:job_histories).where(["job_histories.company_id = ? and job_histories.end_year != ?", 2, "Present"])
```

I also get the same person.

However, if I chain them together to find talents where current employer is Airbnb AND previous employer is Youtube, like this:

```
@talents = Talent.all
@talents = @talents.joins(:job_histories).where(["job_histories.company_id = ? and job_histories.end_year = ?", 1, "Present"])
@talents = @talents.joins(:job_histories).where(["job_histories.company_id = ? and job_histories.end_year != ?", 2, "Present"])
```

I do not get any results. I've tried several variations of the query but none return anything.

The only way I can get it to work is by using the first query and then looping over each talent to find where job_histories.company_id == 2.

```
if params[:advanced_current_company] && params[:advanced_previous_company]
      @talents = @talents.joins(:job_histories).where(job_histories: { company_id: params[:advanced_current_company] }).distinct if params[:advanced_current_company]
      @talents.each do |talent|
        talent.job_histories.each do |job_history|
          if job_history.company_id == params[:advanced_previous_company][0].to_i
            new_talents.append(talent.id)
          end
        end
      end
      @talents = Talent.where(id: new_talents)
```

end

Any direction would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure but can you check if the following is having the proper query you need:
`Talent.joins(:job_histories).where(" (job_histories.company_id = ? and job_histories.end_year = ?) AND (job_histories.company_id = ? and job_histories.end_year != ?) ", 1, 'Present', 2, 'Present') ` 
Also, If this doesn't work check the SQL string it generates by using to_sql at the end if it creates the query you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the right idea with a double join of the `job_histories`, but you need to alias the `job_histories` table names to be able to differentiate between them in the query, as otherwise `activerecord` will think it's only one join that needs to be done.

```
Talent.joins("INNER JOIN job_histories as jh1 ON jh1.talent_id = talents.id")
      .joins("INNER JOIN job_histories as jh2 ON jh2.talent_id = talents.id")
      .where("jh1.company_id = ? and jh1.end_year = ?", 1, "Present")
      .where("jh2.company_id = ? and jh2.end_year != ?", 2, "Present")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much! As a step further, how would I make this work with an array of company IDs instead of only a single company ID? Thanks again!

Comment: @JoelVelis I'm not sure what is the expected result. For passing an array to the query you can do `.where("jh2.company_id in (?)", [2,3])` or even simpler `.where("jh2.company_id": [2,3])`. But this might or might not suffice depending on what is your expected result.

Comment: Also exactly what I needed. Thank you very much Daniel